# Using variable name for selector in less

Tags: less

Is there a way to use a variable name to store the selector and use it?

```
#master #leftcontent div,
#master #rightcontent div{
    background-color: #fff;    
}

#master #leftcontent a,
#master #rightcontent a{
    color:blue;    
}
```

Is it possible to store #master #leftcontent in a variable and refer it

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Yes, this can be done

This works in LESS 1.3.1+. You can vary the string, but this is simply an example of one way it could be done:

**LESS**

```
@selector1: ~'#master';
@selector2: ~'@{selector1} #leftcontent';
@selector3: ~'@{selector1} #rightcontent';

@{selector2} div,
@{selector3} div { 
   background-color: #fff; 
}

@{selector2} a,
@{selector3} a { 
   color: blue; 
}
```

**CSS Output** is exactly as you show in the question.

Comment: Can i use @selector1: '&:hover, &:focus, &:active'; and push it into an selecor as: a { ... @{selector1} { ... } }?

Comment: how do i precede the value with a `.` to be used in a selector?@selector: .~{@currentMember};
        @selector div

Comment: @chovy: Assuming `@currentMember` is a string with the class name you desire, then `@selector: ~'.@{currentMember}'; @{selector} div { ... }`

Comment: Is it possible to do @{aside}: ~'#master &';  (include a '&' in the selector string) ?? I can't seem to do it...

Comment: @olefrank: First, you have a syntax issue in that it should be "@aside:" (without the brackets when assigning the string, with the brackets when interpolating the string to a variable). However, second, it still is not going to work as you want, because the parent selector (&) is not recognized as such when placed into a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here looking to put a media query selector in a less variable (that's how I got here) you can do this:

```
@phone-width: 600px;
@phone: ~"screen and (max-width: @{phone-width})";

@media @phone {
  background-color: white;
}
```